# Worker processes in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a CPU intensive Celery task and within one of the task it can be further parallelized using joblib. By default, starting a worker with celery, will create a pool with number of max concurrency equal to number of CPUs/cores (which is 36 in my case).

My question is, using this configuration, does it mean that each worker process will have only 1 core to use and will not benefit from the parallelization of joblib? or will it use all the cores when there is no other task in the queue of the worker.

For example:

```
@app.task  # picked by celery worker process
def a_task():
    algo = Algo(n_jobs=5)  # further parallelization in the task
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. - Celery can't restrict worker-process to use a single core. It is up to the operating system how it spreads the load of those 36 worker processes but yes you can say that each will have a core to run on. Just to remind you, the worker processes barely take CPU in your case. Most of the CPU time will be used by joblib.

Tasks executed by the Celery worker processes use joblib.Parallel and no matter what backend you pick (multiprocessing or threading) you end up overutilising. (Using joblib.Parallel with n_jobs=1 makes no sense in this context I think)

This means that under heavy load, each core on your machine will run 1 Celery worker process, and many (depends on j_jobs value) joblib.Parallel processes or threads (depending on the backend setting).

Comment: If we are talking about CPython, the interpreter itself restricts execution of single process to only one core.

Comment: That is what the Celery worker processes are - individual CPython interpreter processes. But keep in mind that in this case the tasks running inside these worker-processes use joblib.Parallel and spawn either n_jobs processes or threads depending on the backend type. Nothing restricts CPython process to create child processes and/or threads!

Comment: Sure thing, I was only precising your statement "Celery can't restrict worker-process to use a single core". Worker-process is restricted to single core by CPython implementation. The rest of your answer and comment is precise and valid. No need for exclamation mark.

Comment: I stay behind what I wrote. Celery can't stop its worker-process - Python process - to use all available cores to the maximum... That can _only_ be done by the operating system (via `taskset` tool for an example).

Comment: yes you are right but it seems that joblib is not compatible with celery worker process (billard to be more specific)... joblib only works if you set the backend to `threading`. Otherwise, it will force joblib to use jobs=1 as per this (link)[https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4551#issuecomment-427325793]